# get row number and column name of an data-table (CDK datatable) on clicking on perticular cell

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using `angular 4` and displaying data in angular material provided data-table [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) I have able to create it successfully ,When i am clicking on a row i want to log the `row number` and the `column name` . Here is my below code

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <cdk-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="example-table">
    <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
          The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

    <!-- ID Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userId">
      <cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef class="example-header-cell"> ID </cdk-header-cell>
      <cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" class="example-cell"> {{row.id}} </cdk-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Progress Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="progress">
      <cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef class="example-header-cell"> Progress </cdk-header-cell>
      <cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" class="example-cell"> {{row.progress}}% </cdk-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="userName">
      <cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef class="example-header-cell"> Name </cdk-header-cell>
      <cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" class="example-cell"> {{row.name}} </cdk-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Color Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="color">
      <cdk-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef class="example-header-cell">Color</cdk-header-cell>
      <cdk-cell *cdkCellDef="let row" class="example-cell"
                [style.color]="row.color">
        {{row.color}}
      </cdk-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <cdk-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" class="example-header-row"></cdk-header-row>
    <cdk-row *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="example-row"></cdk-row>
  </cdk-table>
</div>
```